# Getting a System time in java

Tags: java, jodatime

```
static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mma");
static DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
static Chronology coptic = GJChronology.getInstance(zone);
static DateTime dt = new DateTime(coptic);
System.out.println("time is :::"+ dateFormat.format(dt.toDate()));
```

I am using the above piece of code to get a system time and it installed in websphere server.

Actually, its returning only server start up time not current time.Please guide me to get current time.

Comment: This program returns the time in which your program runs.

Comment: Suppose server start at 7 pm and application triggered at 10 pm ,then its not returning only 7 pm not 10 pm.please guide me in which place i need to change

Comment: It seems you want a Coptic representation but choose a formatter (`SimpleDateFormat`) which is not capable of displaying a coptic calendar date. But if you choose the `DateTimeFormatter` of Joda-Time then you will surely not get Coptic month names but just numbers. Is that your real problem? By the way: `GJChronology` is NOT coptic but julian/gregorian.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current date and time, you can use one of the following:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date));
```

or using Calendar.getInstance(),

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc of [`GJChronology`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/GJChronology.html) says:

> Wherever possible, it is recommended to use the `ISOChronology` instead.

So you should just use:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
```

For printing the date/time, you should either lowercase the `HH` or remove the `a`, since 24-hour clock with AM/PM is wrong:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a")
                               .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("time is :::"+ dt.toString(dateFormat));
```